# SubPaging Php with if else

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time passing values so here is the code:

These is the code to pass the values(**$vview** is the container of the value) to be used when showing the sub page: from **enrollalpha.php**

```
   if(!empty($_POST['Vpanel'])){
             $vview = $_POST['Vpanel'];
             }else {
                 if(!empty($_GET['VPanel'])){                
                 $vview= $_GET['VPanel'];
                }else{
                 $vview= 'VS';
                }
             }
```

And this is the codes where **$vview** is to be used

```
if($vview == 'VS'){
            require_once 'vpanel_student.php';
        }
        else if($vview == 'VA'){
            require_once 'vpanel_adviser.php';
        }
        else if($vview == 'VA'){
            require_once 'vpanel_adviser.php';
        }else{
            require_once 'vpanel_student.php';
        }
```

let us assume my subpage now is showing **vpanel_adviser.php** at the said page i have this code:

```
    else if(empty($_GET['id'])){
               header("location:enrollalpha.php?&VPanel='VA'");

            }
```

So at **enrollalpha.php** remember i have this

```
    if(!empty($_GET['VPanel'])){                 
             $vview= $_GET['VPanel'];
            }else{
             $vview= 'VS';
            }
```

my current problem is when **vpanel_adviser.php** returns the user to **enrollalpha.php** it is not showing **vpanel_adviser.php** but shows **vpanel_student.php** Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to quote the value in the URL and unneeded "&" in the URI string.

```
header("location:enrollalpha.php?&VPanel='VA'");
                              // ^   &   ^ Here
```

Change to

```
header("location:enrollalpha.php?VPanel=VA");
```